# Can't understand a line in VHDL

Tags: vhdl

I have encountered this line:

`ADD1 <= ((15 downto 13 => Pixel1_Result(12)) & Pixel1_Result) + ((15 downto 13 => Pixel2_Result(12)) & Pixel2_Result);`

`15 downto 13` means bits from the 15th to the 13th of what?

Comment: It means bits from 15th to 13th position.

Comment: @MituRaj, the 15th to 13th position of what bus?

Comment: Of the ADD1 bus.

Comment: Not of the ADD1 bus, but of the inputs to the adder which drive ADD1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would guess ADD1 is a 17 bit signed type?

Break it down, You don't say, but I think the input is two 13 bit pixel values (Pixel1_result and Pixel2_result) which are being added.

(15 downto 13 => Pixel1_Result(12)) is setting the bits 15 downto 13 of the intermediate value to feed the adder to the value of bit 12 of Pixel1_Result, which is almost certainly being done to sign extend the result.

((15 downto 13 => Pixel1_Result(12)) & Pixel1_Result) is concatenating the pixel data producing a 16 bit signed quantity sign extended from the top bit of the 13 bit Pixel1_Result, same for the bit the other side of the + with Pixel2_Result.

The addition is then adding two signed 16 bit values giving a 17 bit result.

I am slightly surprised that it compiled, I would have expected the types of the intermediate data to need to be explicit, but VHDL has plenty of fun edge cases.

This is NOT the clearest thing I have ever seen and I would personally throw it back in a code review, not least for the magic constants, but also because sign extending into a couple of explicitly declared signals and then adding them would be clearer.